Two stage garage/addition?
I’d like to add a primary suite, living room, and garage to my home. The only thing I need urgently though is a garage so I was considering undergoing a two phase process. First I’d get a garage built that is significantly larger than my needs (I’d store three cars, but not finish the interior for a few years.

Concrete slab for cars (and basketball/pickleball/shop).
Plumbing for future bathroom and electricity.
30x60x30 with open interior (no poles) where 1/3 is dedicated for cars.
Level with existing house floor (no step up/down).

Then I would plan for a second event to add the following.

insulate.
add full bathroom and HVAC.
add large floor to ceiling windows.
add second floor.
attach to house.
add ceiling skylights.

Would breaking up this addition into two usable phases add significant cost? Or, where would I want to be especially conscious in the construction of phase 1 to minimize added overhead to phase 2? Would you recommend against this idea for reasons I might not be thinking of? I was researching metal barnoniums as well.

How long before the second phase.  I would imagine adding the second floor at the same time as the garage(even unfinished) would be cheaper than adding a roof for just a short amount of time(a year or two) and ripping the roof down.

Maybe 5 years. I was imagining it’d be a ~30ft high structure so the second floor would be internal.

The second floor might be needed for building strength.  Maybe just joists/sub floor and supports.  The space for the windows should be done/planned when putting the second floor walls in, really all outside work should be done.

Thank you for this insight!

"attach to house." So this structure is being built standalone away from the current house and you would connect them later with a breezeway?

Also, can you tell use basic info about the house (# of floors facing the planned garage, slab or basement, electric panel size, heating/cool system used, etc) and how close you plan to build the garage?

For attach, I was thinking enclosed but not much more than a walkway.
The house is two stories and the basement is on the other side of the house—it’s only a slab on the side relevant to this garage. The electric panel is on the other side of the house but was recently expanded with a new subpanel. The heating is water radiator by fuel oil and the AC barely covers the existing structure so I thought I’d add minisplit heat pump/ac unit(s) to the addition. I’m in PA so imagine I’d need a propane heater to supplement/spot-heat versus heat pump for that area.

There’s zoning against building within 20ft, but I’d hope something closer to 10ft with permits to connect them, but not act on it immediately

As long as you design and plan for both temporary and ultimate conditions, I don't see why you can't stage it.  Note that the odds of codes changing in the intervening time aren't zero, even though they're probably very low.
